# Turning off/un USB power to reset a mobile broadband internet device

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a GUI web scraping that makes some requests in a webpage. Recently this webpage is blocking my public ip address from access in it after some requests.

VPN providers are being unsuccessful since the webpage ends up blocking them permanently.

I tried refreshing the ip device but the only way I have found is turning it off by extracting it physically. As the web scraping can't do it I'm trying to power off the USB but I can't find how.